# Onejar-maven-plugin to set the order of jar loading

Tags: maven, classloader, slf4j, logback, onejar

I've been using the library **apache-log4j-extras** for logging. It contains class **org.apache.log4j.Logger**.

Now I had to reference some 3rd party library, that uses *logback* and has among its dependencies **log4j-over-slf4j** (jar). Unfortunately, latter jar also contains class **org.apache.log4j.Logger**.

Looks like the latter class is preferred by the onejar classloader...

I don't need *logback* and *log4j-over-slf4j*. Just want my **org.apache.log4j.Logger** from **apache-log4j-extras** back. What are my options with the Onejar-maven-plugin?

**EDIT:** It appeared to be an issue with Debug mode in IDEA, not with onejar. However the question is still relevant: how can I ensure that I load the requried class with Onejar?

**EDIT2:** E.g. in C# it could be easily resolved with "[extern alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212.aspx)" feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you just exclude it?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>my.naughty.thirdparty</groupId>
    <artifactId>thirdparty-with-log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>${thirdparty.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like (**for Debug mode in IDEA**) just switching depenencies order solved the issue.

How it was:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>my.naughty.thirdparty</groupId>
        <artifactId>thirdparty-ref-log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>0.50</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>apache-log4j-extras</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Changed to:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>apache-log4j-extras</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>my.naughty.thirdparty</groupId>
        <artifactId>thirdparty-ref-log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>0.50</version>
    </dependency>
```

But surely I can't consider it as a robust solution, especially for Onejar.